# Slick: Codegen foreign key references

Tags: scala, orm, code-generation, slick, slick-2.0

I am using [slick 2.x's codegen](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0-M2/code-generation.html) feature to generate Scala models from database schema. However, is it possible to traverse foreign key constraints to generate related models e.g. if I have this schema

```
CREATE TABLE people(id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(31));
CREATE TABLE dogs(name VARCHAR(31), ownerId INT FOREIGN KEY people(id));
```

I get the following models from slick:

```
case class PeopleRow(id: Int, name: String)
case class DogsRow(name: String, ownerId: Int)
```

But, what I actually want is this:

```
case class PeopleRow(id: Int, name: String)
case class DogsRow(name: String, owner: PeopleRow)
```

or even better:

```
case class PeopleRow(id: Int, name: String) {
  def dogs: List[DogsRow]   // return items from dogs table that has this.id as ownerId
}

case class DogsRow(name: String, ownerId: People) {
  lazy val owner: People  // lazy on-demand or, can be a def too
}
```

Is there anyway to override the slick codegen to do this?

Comment: @EndeNeu: The question though related isn't relevant. He is going from Scala schema to generated SQL. I want the other way. I want to modify the **SQL->Scala** code generator to do this for me...

Comment: I linked the question because you can't have case classes defined as foreign keys, you need to explicitly specify them and they must be some primitive type (Int, Long, etc.). You can't have structured types as keys, unless your use case is different from the sql parent children relationship, in that case yes, that question is not relevant.

Comment: @EndeNeu: I was wondering if I can override the codegen itself so I can add helper `def dogs` (see last example) to the generated case classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do it this way. One of Slick's core strength comes from composing queries. While what you are intending is possible you are breaking this strength. Instead write queries!

```
implicit class PersonExtension(q: Query[Person,PersonRow]){
  def dogs = q.join(Dog).on(_.id === _.ownerId).map(_._2)
}
implicit class DogExtension(q: Query[Person,PersonRow]){
  def owner = q.join(Person).on(_.ownerId === _.id).map(_._2)
}

val personQuery = Person.filter(_.id === someId)
val person = personQuery.first
val dogsQuery = personQuery.dogs
val dogs = dogsQuery.run
val ownerQuery = dogsQuery.owner
val owner = ownerQuery.first
```

So use the old query to base your new dogs query upon. The advantage is that you do not hard code one query this way, but you can compose further. Want only brown dogs? No problem:

```
val brownDogsQuery = personQuery.dogs.filter(_.color === "brown")
```

You can of course generate these implicit classes automatically using the code generator.

Related Videos:

- Scala eXchange 2013
- Scala User Group Berlin talk Dec, 2013
- Scala Days 2014 talk

http://slick.typesafe.com/docs/

Comment: Isn't it nicer to have the implicit classes on the tables instead? e.g. `implicit class PersonExtension(p: Person){ def dogs = Dogs.filter(_.ownerId === p.id) }` This way you could use them in monadic joins.

Comment: No! Having them on the queries allows still using them after applying a filter etc.

Comment: Why not apply the filter (etc) in the monadic join? Example (from my business domain):
    `val query = for`
      `{`
        `user <- Users if user.lastName === "Miller"`
        `relation <- user.loginRelations`
        `role <- relation.role if role.isCentralMonitor`
        `study <- relation.study`
      `} yield (user.firstName, user.lastName, role.name, study.name)`

Comment: sure, you can do that. Leads to slick generating a WHERE rather than an ON.

Comment: Ah, found it in the docs :) monadic → implicit but applicative → explicit (subject to change). I guess database engines are usually smart enough to run them both with the same performance. Not?

Comment: database engines "are usually smart enough to" do X is a pretty dangerous statement, hehe ;). We have seen performance differences between the two in some engines if I recall correctly. MySQL is usually the most quirky